# Is Entity Framework 4.1 is the best solution for a web application that is using almost 400 database tables?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Is Entity Framework 4.1 is the best solution for a web application that is using almost 400 database tables or it would best to make cutome data access layer with straight sql and sp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of tables only affects EF initialization where "views" must be compiled when the context is used first time in the application - 400 is a lot and it will take a lot of time. This can be speed up by generating source code for views and adding these source codes to the project - views will not be compiled at runtime because compiled code will be part of your application but you must manually do this each time you change the model. For EFv4.1 this feature is offered in [EF Power Tools CTP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx). For EDMX the feature is offered in [EdmGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx) command line tool.

Another impact on such number of tables in on development. Using 400 tables in single EDMX seems impossible so you will need multiple contexts with different sets of mapped entities. This can be complex task for application architecture because working with multiple contexts makes everything harder.

If you want to use code only mapping you must either write classes and mapping for 400 tables or you will again use EF Power Tools CTP1 which will generate them for you.

It is not impossible to use EF with 400 tables but it is complex and requires some experience.

Answer (score 0):

Different people may have different views on it. Answer to your question is how you use EF whether it will be poco model or you are going to use edmx? EF performance depends on the number of records as well, so if you are using 10 tables and altogether they have 100 records then ef will perform better.
But still performance of ef on the basis of tables and records is a big question and it depends on various factors including your database designing whether it is properly normalised or not.

Answer (score 0):

We do have more than 1000 tables, and we are using it (its a web app). You do not have to put everything in a single model, that would make it pretty darn hard to work on the model itself. And we are using Code Only approach, its in development yet, but everything works fine so far.